# position elements over image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to position some elements over an image while keeping the following behaviour:

- when in mobile stop floating the `"muuh"` text to the right
- keep text aligned with the bottom of the image
- The `.item` `div` size should not be bigger than the image

What i've achieved so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wn6M9/14/

This at the moment doesn't work as you can see by the `div` background, nor is the text aligned with the bottom of the picture.

[image: result so far]

Comment: Do you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6M9/15/)?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Nop,i want the pink part aligned with the blue bottom and the black gone. I think you've just removed the "stop floating text to the right in mobile" requirement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wn6M9/16/ Maybe like this?

Comment: @MateiMihai That is the text below the image, i'm trying to get the text over the image and getting rid of the space below the image, the "black" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/E5x7q/)

I changed the `CSS` to:

```
.masonry {
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.item-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.item-text {
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}

.item-title {
    padding: 0px;
}

.item-right {
    padding: 0px;
}

@media(min-width:992px){
    .item-creator {
        float: right !important;   
    }
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle 2</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/QHTWC/) - Pink bit at bottom of image

Comment: Awesome, is there a way to make the text bottom align to the bottom of the image?

Comment: Do you mean the pink bit at the bottom of the image? @GriffinHeart

Comment: If you did, I added another link in my answer @GriffinHeart

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for

```
.item-title {
border:0px solid black;
padding: 0px;
float:left;
}

.item-right {
padding: 0px;
border:0px solid black;
float:right;
}
```